# Python Error : ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
attacklist=[]
attacklist=list(attack.values())
nonattacklist=[]
nonattacklist=list(non_attack.values())


for i in attacklist:
    if i in nonattacklist:
        nonattacklist.remove(i)
print(attacklist)
print(nonattacklist)
```

I am getting value error when trying to run this code, I read the previous 2 answers but they didn't work out for me. `attacklist` and `nonattacklist` are two 2D lists.

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IDS.py", line 149, in <module>
    if i in nonattacklist:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is happening.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: What's `attack`?  What do you mean by 2d list?  Careful with that `list(...)`.  It may not be working as you expect?

Comment: attack is a dictionary

Comment: ok, then list is right.  But we  still need to know exacly what's going on in `i in nonattacklist` (assuming that's the error line)

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]. Have you looked up this error? Because there are many questions about this error on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [58]: alist = [np.arange(4), np.array([4,3,6,4])]
In [59]: alist
Out[59]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 3, 6, 4])]
In [60]: 8 in alist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-60-79aec61015f7>", line 1, in <module>
    8 in alist
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

or

```
In [62]: np.array([3,2,3,2]) in alist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-62-f109595cabfd>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([3,2,3,2]) in alist
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So in:

```
for i in attacklist:
    if i in nonattacklist:
```

`nonattacklist` must be a list of arrays, and `attacklist` probably is one also.

If you really have a list of lists, then the `in` will work:

```
In [63]: alist = [a.tolist() for a in alist]
In [64]: alist
Out[64]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 6, 4]]
In [66]: [0,1,2,3] in alist
Out[66]: True
```

This ambiguity error is produced only by `numpy`.  (`pandas` uses a different wording).

Answer (score -1):

Based out of your input , assuming `attack` and `non_attack` being a dictionary `values()` returns a `dict_values` which you can think of as a `list`.

Hence `attacklist` and `nonattacklist` are list of lists, and since each element is a list and `in` operator expects a `scalar` value to work

You require another loop to check the element if it exists.

```
attacklist=[]
attacklist=list(attack.values())
nonattacklist=[]
nonattacklist=list(non_attack.values())


for elem_outer in attacklist:
    #### elem_outer is list
    for elem in elem_outer:
        ### elem is the element under elem_outer
        if i in nonattacklist:
            nonattacklist.remove(i)
print(attacklist)
print(nonattacklist)
```

The best way would be to use `dictionaries` for element checking

```
from pprint import pprint

attack = dict()
non_attack = dict()

for i in attack:
    if attack[i] in non_attack:
        non_attack.pop(attack[i],None)
pprint(attack)
pprint(non_attack)
```

Comment: "Hence attacklist and nonattacklist are list of lists, and since each element is a list and in operator expects a scalar value to work" That is absolutely not true.

Comment: If those variables were lists of lists, it would not produce a `numpy` array error.  `"The truth value of an array ...'`.  Either `i` or `nonattacklist` is an array

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Meant a nested list , not primarily list of list

Comment: @hpaulj - I mean a nested structure here , not primarily a list of lists

Comment: I don't what you mean by nested structure.  That's not a well defined concept in python.